# Rails: Cannot access column from a join-table in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, partial

I want to access a column from a join-table in a partial. When I access this column in a "normal" view (e.g. fakeposts#index) it is working, however if I want to do the same in a partial, it does not work.

**Example:**

I have a users and a fakeposts table. For each user I want to display the fakeposts in a specific (randomized) order - namely based on a randomized_time column -, which is saved in a join table:

**randomized_posts table:**

```
user_id | fakepost_id | randomized_time
```

My Models look like this:

```
#user.rb
has_many :randomized_fakeposts

#fakepost.rb
has_many :randomized_fakeposts

# randomized_fakepost.rb
belongs_to :fakepost
belongs_to :user
```

In my fakepost_controller.rb I want to get the fakeposts for the current_user and add the column "randomized_time" to my selection:

**My fakepost_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @fakeposts = Fakepost.joins(:randomized_fakeposts).where(randomized_fakeposts: {user_id: current_user.id}).select("fakeposts.*, randomized_fakeposts.randomized_time")
end
```

**This is working: index.html.erb**

```
<% @fakeposts.each do |post| %>
   <%= post.randomized_time %>
<% end %>
```

**This is not working: index.html.erb and my partial**

```
#index.html.erb
<% @fakeposts.each do |post| %>
   <%= render :partial => "layouts/individual-post", :locals => {:post => post} %>
<% end %>

#layouts/_individual-post.html.erb
<%= post.randomized_time %>
```

**Error message**

```
=> undefined method `randomized_time' for #<Fakepost:0x007f7752eeab58>
```

However, something like <%= post.created_at %> is working fine in my partial so I guess the way I call my partial is correct?

Comment: Seems like you have a typo `Fakepost.joins(randomized_fakeposts)` should be `Fakepost.joins(:randomized_fakeposts)`

Comment: Ah, thanks :), I've fixed the typo (since in my code it is correct).

Comment: Does the exact same method work in your rails console?

Comment: @angkiki: Do you mean the post.randomized_time? Yes, I can access post.randomized_time in my rails console.

Comment: Argh, I found the error and it was impossible for outsiders to see it (since I did not provide the whole code for simplicity reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the source of the error and for "outsiders" it was impossible to find (since I did not provide the whole code).

In my FakepostsController.rb I also had:

```
def index
   # This line is the same line like in my original post
   @fakeposts = Fakepost.joins(:randomized_fakeposts).where(randomized_fakeposts: {user_id: current_user.id}).select("fakeposts.*, randomized_fakeposts.randomized_time")
   ...
   # This was the line which causes the error:
   @pinned_fakeposts = Fakepost.where(pinned: true)
end
```

Because my @pinned_fakeposts did not include my "randomized_time" column (I did not .joins it), the error occured.

So what I did was:

```
@pinned_fakeposts = Fakepost.where(pinned: true).joins(:randomized_fposts).where(randomized_fakeposts: {user_id: current_user.id}).select("fakeposts.*, randomized_fakeposts.randomized_time")
```

**Conclusion**

So everything else was fine and it is possible to get your join column in a partial :).